# Are Group Policy entries always written to Registry?

Tags: windows, group-policy

I have some setting

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\NetworkIsolation DWORD DSubnetsAuthoritive
```

which seems to be set but in the Registry nothing is enabled. But when I look for similar named registry keys I find under

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\NetworkIsolation\EnterpriseIPRangesAreAuthoritative
```

a bunch of values:
[image]

Are these settings overriding the other one, or are group policies able to skip registry entirely and write the data elsewhere? I strongly suspect that the values are somehow overriden, but regardless what I change the behavior does not change.
When I do a `gpupdate /force` then these keys above are also not overwritten. I have thought that group policies would overwrite the settings to ensure consistent values but that seems not to be the case.

I have checked with procmon that the firewall service indeed accesses both locations but it seems that it gets the final value still from somewhere else. Any pointers where I can look in additon?

Comment: The default key(s) is just that the default values for those policies, if your connected to an AD domain, those policies will take effect if they are different than the default values

Comment: @Ramhound: So the values will be updated depending on the default values in this registry key? If I change the defaults, then I can work around group policy settings? Does it really work this way? The actual set values are then stored under Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\current\device\ ? Which values are set by an gpupdate /force the defaults, the current\device ones?

Comment: Only the current device values are updated.  Is there a reason you are not using the gpeditor?

Comment: @Ramhound: I am no domain admin. I have read about ADMX, CSP and now Intune. I am never sure what group policies are doing and if the viewer is showing the actual data, or if some newer approach is used which I am not aware of.

Comment: You can't push group policies updates, from a client connected to a AD Domain, since the AD Domain will just override your changes the minute the user logs into the domain or the machine is rebooted

Comment: @Ramhound: I want to find out which group policy setting overrides NetworkIsolation. I am pretty sure that value is set, but I cannot find which Registry key is used by the Firewall. Based on the values I see it should not be set at all, but the Firewall behavior tells me that this setting is somehow enabled.